# Iterative Function results into Matrix or Data Frame on R

Tags: r, matrix, iteration, rstudio

The output of my iterative function prints fine, but how do I get it to save as a data frame/matrix object?

```
     for(i in id){
            print(data.frame("ID" = i, "nobs" = length(data4[data4 == i])))
    }


     ID nobs
   1  1  117
      ID nobs
    1  2 1041
      ID nobs
    1  3  243
      ID nobs
    1  4  474
     ID nobs
   1  5  402
     ID nobs
   1  6  228
     ID nobs
   1  7  442
     ID nobs
    1  8  192
```

I've tried creating a matrix beforehand, but if I try to assign it to the matrix, I get a NULL value.

```
    mat.obs <- matrix(NA, nrow = 332, ncol = 2)
    for(i in id){
            print(data.frame("ID" = i, "nobs" = length(data4[data4 == i])))
            mat.obs <- data.frame("ID" = i, "nobs" = length(data4[data4 == i]))
          }
      }
```

Comment: `data4` is a vector??

Comment: You have to assign the output to rows in 'mat.obj`  `mat.obs[i, ] <- c("ID" = i, "nobs" = length(data4[data4 == i]))`

Comment: Can't you just use `table(data4)` as a start? I recommend against a `matrix`, since one column has different *units* than the others; though it'll work programmatically, it is a little sloppy. A `data.frame` would be more appropriate, where there is no assumption of columns having the same units. (This seems pedantic for certain, but treating a `matrix` as a single-type thing is "A Good Thing (tm)".)

Comment: Thanks guys. Always learning something new on here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `data.table` like so:

```
library(data.table)
# create a data.table with data4 as a column named 'id'
DT = data.table(id = data4)

# count observations with each ID
DT[ , .N, by = id]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
ldply(id, function(i) data.frame("ID" = i, "nobs" = length(data4[data4 == i])))
```